# How to rerender component after object update?

Tags: react-native, render, rerender

I'm trying to update rating average after a user gives her own rating. I managed to update the object, but not sure how to make it rerender component, so new average would show up. My code for this part:

```js
const pizza = props.route?.params?.pizza ?? null;

const rateClicked = () => {
    doRate(pizza.id, highlight, token)
    .then( resp => {
        Alert.alert("Rating", resp.message);
        doGetDetails(pizza.id, token).then( resp => {
            pizza.avg_rating = resp.avg_rating;
        });
    })
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: Can you not just set the rating as a state and then update the state?

Comment: const rateClicked runs onPress and I'm not sure how I could rerender component if I would use setState. I cannot put const rateClicked into useFocusEffect. I'm new to this, so maybe my approach is not very smart

Comment: is this a classbased or functional component?

Comment: functional: 
`export default function Details(props) {`

Comment: if you are using hooks you can set a state hook for the rating and just change the rating to what the user enters in an inputtext to be the new state. if not because its functional you have to use redux or just use a classbased approach

Comment: Ok, I will try to look into how I could make it work with hooks. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can update state (Hooks)

```
export default function Details(props) {
 
  const [pizzaData, setPizzaData] = useState(props.pizza); <-- "props.pizza" is default -->

  const rateClicked = () => {
    doRate(pizza.id, highlight, token)
    .then( resp => {
        Alert.alert("Rating", resp.message);
        doGetDetails(pizza.id, token).then( resp => {
            const pizzaData = {...pizzaData};
            pizzaData.avg_rating = resp.avg_rating;
            setPizzaData(pizzaData); // reset state here to rerender 
        });
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help! I've just tried this, but the outcome is the same as in my example. Object is being updated, but it does not rerender until I toggle something on the component (in my case I have 5 starts which user taps to set the rating and then clicks Rate button). It does update after I select some stars again, but not when I click Rate button. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks! With your help I did it! However, some information if anyone else will encounter a similar question: `const pizzaData = {...pizzaData};` - this leaves object empty, so it is not enouth to set avg_rating, but I had to set whole object `pizza` from `resp`. Like this: 
`const rateClicked = () => {
    doRate(pizza.id, highlight, token)
    .then( resp => {
        Alert.alert("Rating", resp.message);
        doGetDetails(pizza.id, token).then( resp => {
            const pizza = {...pizza};
            setPizza(resp);
        });`

Answer (score 1):

In order for a component to re-render, you should have either a state or a props variable to change.

In your case, when you update with `doRate`, to change it in the props data re-fetch should be done in the parent component.
Or you can change a state variable:

```js
const pizza = props.route?.params?.pizza ?? null;

const rateClicked = () => {
    doRate(pizza.id, highlight, token)
    .then( resp => {
        Alert.alert("Rating", resp.message);
        doGetDetails(pizza.id, token).then( resp => {
            this.setState(avg_rating: resp.avg_rating);
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: I've had to change colon to a comma, so IDE would not to show any errors: 
`this.setState(pizza.avg_rating, resp.avg_rating)`. However, I get `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.setState')]`. I'm not yet that familiar with "this", sorry about that and thanks for your help

Comment: I don't suggest you copy-paste the code, but rather see what it's trying to do.
you didn't provide the whole component, so I was just guessing that this is a class component.
apparently, you have a functional component that's why `this.setState` throws an error